# Angular 2/4 interface declaration concern

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I find out that in angular, we have to declare an interface before processing with a JSON data from a server.
Its okay with a small json structure but let's assume we have a large json file with a hundred of key-value pair I think its difficult to create an exact interface in our app.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: you can create an object of type `any` if u don't want to create an interface , anyway i don't think that there is a way to create a dynamic Interface or something like that..

Comment: I think this is more a question about TypeScript rather than Angular

Answer (score 1):

You don't must to create an Interface. You want to create an interface so you can enjoy the benefits of a strongly-typed language (typescript).

You can just use "any" instead but you'll still have to remember the elements of the "json" in order to access its values.